# Is memory cleanup on a div automatic for the children?

Tags: javascript, html, memory

I have an html div that has about 6 divs under it. When I remove a Child on that div will the other divs be unallocated or must I first remove them? the divs are dynamically created.

```
 var window = document.createElement( 'div' );
```

then I add more elements to it.  Later on at some point I want to remove these divs and I do so with removeElement on the top level div. Is that going to cause memory issue in the browser? If so would I be correct in thinking I must remove each child first.

Comment: Why don't you just try ?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: What `div`are you talking about, HTML div ? What programming language are you using ? Please add relevent tags to your question and consider showing us some code

Comment: I can't add my code because this silly system complains. Add more text if you want to add code... Anyways I dont know what this question mark stuff is all about. Though this is HTML code and I'm making divs dynamically. 
     var window = document.createElement( 'div' ); ... and adding more divs to it.

Answer (score 3):

The very short answer is ... Yes (because you don't have to do it manually) and No (because it isn't neccesarily done the way you assume), but don't worry about it.

Your html code is so far abstracted from the actual memory management, it's not really even a valid question.

When elements are removed from the DOM, all their child nodes are removed too. Adding an element doesn't directly allocate a block of memory - it adds a single node to the DOM which is then used by the rendering process. The size of a node is usually trivially small.

When a node is removed, the browser probably won't release memory as the DOM itself is still active but you shouldn't worry about it. Your only real concern is the number of elements being rendered/manipulated concurrently.

Comment: I kind of felt that was the case. c++ coder witting html is bad ;) Thx for the straight answer.

Comment: My pleasure. Welcome to SO and I hope we see you around more in future.